# how to properly halt linux system when exiting init

Tags: bash, linux-kernel, qemu, shutdown, init

In Qemu, I'm starting a linux VM where init process (PID 1) is bash.
It is working : I can use bash after boot.
But when I quit bash with a `exit` or `CTRL+D` I got a kernel panic.

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000000
```

I'd like the system to halt properly and ideally, I'd like it to sync disk before when quitting bash.

Is it possible, knowing that I can modify kernel behavior only by passing options at boot ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that directly, but you can run, e.g.

```
# bash; sync; halt
```

from the first (PID 1) shell to run another one, and to run `sync` and `halt` when that second shell exits.

If you can edit the files on the system, you could probably automate that by putting
a script doing the same in `/sbin/init`:

```
#/bin/sh
/bin/bash; /bin/sync; /sbin/halt
```

(I say "probably", because I'm not sure if Linux likes a script as init.)

In both cases, the shell you'd actually use would not be PID 1, but that probably doesn't matter much.